# Automate apex execution

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I have a piece of apex code which checks if the user hasn't  logged in over a certain period of time it disables. So my question now is how often should I run this code and is there a way to automate the execution of my code every day to make it hassle free process.

Comment: You can write `Apex Batch` to Process them on daily/weekly basis or it depends on the requirement when to schedule the `Batch`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a class that's Schedulable. This class can then be scheduled at a regular interval. The frequency of your Apex code should be a business decision, rather than a technical one - so not much I can say about that!

Please refer to the documentation about the Schedulable interface: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

Comment: I saw the like and it is really helpful. Any suggestions how should I work around test class for this? Note: - In my class, I am fetching users with particular profile and seeing if they ever logged in since creation or haven't logged in since a long time and deactivate them.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation, under the heading "Testing the Apex Scheduler"! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can automate your process using a **batch apex** you just have to write your existing code in the execute method of a class which implements a **batchable interface** . After that you have to write a **scheduler** for that batch class by which you can schedule your class on hourly,Weekly,monthly or yearly basis.You can write a cron expression for your scheduler to run for every minute also.You can visit the below links to write the batch and scheduler class.

How to write a batch class.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

How to write a scheduler class

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

Comment: This logic would only need to be batchable if you had over 10k records to act on or 50k records total. With the `User` table, that seems unlikely.